# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested still can't access

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

How can i fix been debugging but i can't really figure it out

This is my ERROR

```
Access to fetch at 'BACK END URL' from origin 'CLIENT URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

const app = (0, express_1.default)();
app.use(express_1.default.json());
const setCorsHeader = (response) => {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", configs_json_1.default.clientURL);
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    response.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "300");
    return response;
};


> i tried like to put this code
> but still got the errror


const cors=require("cors");
app.use(cors({
origin: "CLIENT URL",
method: ["POST", "GET", "OPTIONS"]

}));
```

> App.js:190     POST BACK END URL 404 (Not Found)
> (anonymous) @ App.js:190
> f @ regeneratorRuntime.js:86
> (anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:66
> (anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:117
> l @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
> i @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
> (anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
> (anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
> (anonymous) @ App.js:179
> (anonymous) @ App.js:232
> f @ regeneratorRuntime.js:86
> (anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:66
> (anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:117
> l @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
> i @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
> (anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
> (anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
> (anonymous) @ App.js:231
> ru @ react-dom.production.min.js:244
> Ss @ react-dom.production.min.js:286
> (anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:282
> S @ scheduler.production.min.js:13
> L @ scheduler.production.min.js:14
> App.js:224 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, <DOCTYPE  is not valid JSON

Comment: does your code send a valid `Response to preflight`

Comment: yes it just can't be access on my Client URL

Comment: the first bit of code doesn't seem to handle pre-flight, and the second bit of code doesn't seem to allow content-type header

Comment: do you have idea where did i go wrong? like what should i do.. i use nginx to host it